# How to get similar functionality of Expect in a C program

Tags: c, expect

I have the below expect script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 60
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set command [lindex $argv 2]

spawn su $user
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";
send "$command\r";
send "exit\r";
interact
```

How do i do the similar operations in C?
AFAIK the header expect.h provides similar functionality but i am kind of lost while using it
Any help is appreciated

Comment: what did you tried so far? Please edit your question.

Comment: I haven't used it either, but have you checked the man page for libexpect?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not locked on expect, i believe the easiest way to handle the execution of another process is via [forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty).

It allows you executing a process and control its input/output via a file descriptor.

[Here](http://thebends.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/pty-example.c) is just an example i googled for.